# adding to the previous total variable

Tags: python

file = file_name
    totalx = shirt_mm+pant_mm+sale_mm+deposite_mm+coat_mm+sari_mm

```
#full stock info for showing in nother window
sub = withdraw_mm + buy_mm

saving = ['0']

full = totalx
full_money = full + totalx
left_over = full_money - sub
```

I am trying to make a variable or list which will keep the previous value of integer and when the function is called with the change in variables it the variable would add the input to the previous integer value.

Comment: Please don't be sloppy in your questions. Format your code and ask an actual question.

Comment: suppose #x  = 0,  #y = Input  I want a way to to keep record in x every time there is y new input with the previous y to x

Comment: You're not hearing me. Please edit your question, and use the preview to make sure the formatting is ok. Your question should not be in the comments.